# How can I get the selected radio button from an intent?

Tags: android, radio-button

I am making an app that let's the user create a discount for the items and I am letting them choose what type. Either by `Percentage` or `Amount`. I have them in my radiogroup.

I have successfully added them and now I want somehow users to update it. What I want to do is to get the checked radio button and display it to my Edit Discount activity. How can I set the checked radio button to the selected one?

Thanks for any help.

Here is how I get the selected item from my AddDiscountActivity.java

```
public void addRadioGroupListener(){
    int radioid = disctype.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    discbtn = (RadioButton) findViewById(radioid);
    selecteddisc = discbtn.getText().toString();
}
```

This is my intent

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String disctype = list.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getDisc_type();

        Intent edit = new Intent(v.getContext(), EditDiscount.class);
        edit.putExtra("discounttype", disctype);
        v.getContext().startActivity(edit);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first Activity write something like this:

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = activity.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
int selectedRadioID = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
RadioButton radioButton = activity.findViewById(selectedRadioID);
String selectedRadioText = radioButton.getText().toString();
Intent edit = new Intent(context, EditDiscount.class);
edit.putExtra("discounttype", selectedRadioText);
context.startActivity(edit);
```

And in your second activity get the text from intent like this:

```
String selectedRadioTxt = getIntent().getExtras().getString("discounttype");
if(selectedRadioTxt.equals(yourRadioButton.getText()))
     yourRadioButton.setChecked(true);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am quite confused, sorry. I made my intent from my recyclerview adapter..

Comment: I am getting an error `int android.widget.RadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()' on a null object reference`

Comment: Could you please share the recyclerview adapter's complete code? (Just update your question)

Comment: Hi, I doubled checked and found out that the `discount type` is not displayed in my layout that is why it was not saved in my intent. What I did was I retrieved `discount type` data from my firebase and applied your code in the last part (without the intent of course :) ) and it worked. Thanks!